# Determine if begindate is weekend

Tags: c#

I need to check if the selected date from a datepicker is not on a weekend. The function needs to keep checking if the new startdate is a weekend. Also it need to add days to the startdate if a weekend occurs.

Code should be something like this:

```
int startday = Datepicker1.SelectedDate;
if (startdate = weekendday, startdate++)
{
 startdate++ //or if a sunday +2
}
else
{
 return startdate
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: that code doesn't even compile

Comment: I know it doesn't compile it just gives you guys a direction whitch way i want to go.

Comment: Please, at least provide a working code sample to show that you have put some effort in this question.

Comment: If you want the code to handle the weekend by country, I have a method to do that at http://blogs.windward.net/davidt/2013/10/12/is-it-the-weekend/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
if (startdate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    startdate = startdate.AddDays(2);
else if (startdate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    startdate = startdate.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: DateTime is immutable. startdate.AddDays(2) will do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `DayOfWeek` property you can explicitly check for weekend days.  Something like this:

```
if ((startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) ||
    (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
```

Of course, that's a bit long for a conditional.  Abstracting it to a helper method makes it a little cleaner:

```
private bool IsWeekend(DateTime date)
{
    return (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) ||
           (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
}
```

To use like this:

```
if (IsWeekend(startDate))
```

Or, perhaps a little cleaner, you could write an extension method for `DateTime`:

```
public static bool IsWeekend(this DateTime date)
{
    return (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) ||
           (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
}
```

Which you would use like this:

```
if (startDate.IsWeekend())
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `DateTime.DayOfWeek` documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx).

```
while(startday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday 
         || startday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
   startday = startday.AddDays(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `DateTime.DayOfWeek` property.
Nice example from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`DateTime.DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx) property - it will give you the day of the week on which your DateTime object falls.